# importing json file to mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

I am a student doing my undergrad in IT. So far I have done all my data management using RDBMS. I have built few stand alone systems using java -jdbc - rdbms..After going through the NoSQL concepts, I would like to use MongoDB for my future project work.. I have few questions..I will be reading Mongodb documentation and learnCRUD operations. I want to choose a decent dataset and import it into mongodb and do some kind of search operations and analytics..is there any link that actually demonstrates importing json data into mongodb..? I m totally new to this? can you please help me?

Comment: Google results [here](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&q=import+mongodb&oq=import+mongodb).

Answer (score 0):

This is the doc on how to insert data (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/create/), MongoDB uses BSON (which is JSON with more types to support binary data).  Create a database and then create a collection and insert your data.  There are many language based libraries that will allow you to connect to Mongo and then do programmatic inserts into the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Start your instance of mongod for example on window as shown below

mongod --dbpath mydb\data --logpath mylogs\logs\log09April2013.log --logappend -journal --rest

Now use the mongoimport to import your data

mongoimport --db pcat -c zips < zips.json

connected to: 127.0.0.1
Mon April 09 11:59:03                     9600    3200/second
Mon April 09 11:59:06                     19500   3250/second
Mon April 09 11:59:08 imported 29470 objects

Regards

Adeyemi Adegbile